# Get integer value from dimens.xml resource file in Android

Tags: android, android-resources

I have an **EditText** which is decimal and I set its length using **android:maxLength** property in xml:

```
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/quantity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:maxLength="@integer/quantity_length" />
```

As its length is going to be used not only in the UI xml file but also in a java class and maybe some other places, I want to avoid problems when I update this value in future, so I want to put the length centralized in the dimens.xml resource file as follows:

**dimens.xml**

```
<resources>

    <!-- other things -->

    <!-- Constants -->
    <item name="quantity_length" format="integer" type="integer">10</item>

    <!-- other things -->

</resources>
```

From a java class I need to read this value so I perform:

```
    TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue();
    this.getResources().getValue(R.integer.quantity_length, typedValue, true);
```

but I can notice that there is no method getInt(), only getFloat():

```
    int digitsBefore = typedValue.getFloat();
```

so as I need to get it as integer.... how to do this? Of course, maybe I can get it using getFloat() and then casting to integer.... but I do not know if it is an elegant way to do it... so any ideas?

UPDATE:
Oooppssss I did a mistake. It is:
    int quantity = typedValue.getFloat();

instead of:

```
int digitsBefore = typedValue.getFloat();
```

Comment: why you are not using `getResources().getDimens` ?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Why not store the integer in **res/integers.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <integer name="quantity_length">12</integer>
</resources>
```

And to access the values in code

```
int myInteger = getResources().getInteger(R.integer.quantity_length);
```

Or in XML

```
android:maxLength="@integer/quantity_length"
```

Comment: Great! I have just discovered right now using getInteger ;) A lot of thanks. Also, I have seen in you recommends to use a separate file "integers.xml" file. Is it more suitable than using the existing dimens.xml file?

Comment: Yes it is intended to store integers, dimens is for storing dimensions like **dp**, **sp** and so on.

Comment: this is not working anymore why ? android:maxLength="@integer/quantity_length"

Answer (score 2):

With your example, why don't you use this method?

XML

```
<integer name="quantity_length">10</integer>
```

JAVA

```
getResources().getInteger(R.integer.quantity_length);
```

Answer (score 1):

You dont need a `TypedValue` use the following

`(int) this.getResources().getDimension(R.integer.quantity_length)`;

Answer (score 1):

```
int max = getContext().getResources().getInteger(R.integer.quantity_length);
```

Answer (score 1):

**I tested with Android Studio 3.3.1 with SDK lollipop**

*Keep an eye on the paths...*

*Clean and build...* I had a pretty hard time, thinking it's not working, but after deleting the file and Re-add, and few clean and build, I got it working strange...

**1. This works ( note the tick and its path)**

[image: works]

**2. Here is proof**

[image: UPDATED ANSWER / February - 2019]

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
Integer.ParseInt(digitsBefore);
```