# How to fix error "Resource ID #0x7f0600c3 type #0x4 is not valid"

Tags: android, gridview

I using gridview with scroll horizontal include 5 1 row, 5 column display data and using code set weight, height for it:

```
int widthCell = getActivity().getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.widthCell);
int heightCell = getActivity().getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.heightCell);
```

But for phone samsum or oppo failed: "Resource ID #0x7f0600c3 type #0x4 is not valid". I don't know how to fix this error. Can you help me? Thanks

Comment: can you paste here your widthCell and heightCell ?

Comment: code above Gaston

Comment: I mean what is inside R.dimen.heightCell

Comment: this Gaston
    <dimen name="widthCell">300dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="heightCell">500dp</dimen>

Comment: If you are loading integers, please refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27782074/get-integer-value-from-dimens-xml-resource-file-in-android

Answer (score 1):

Inside your `values.xml` file please check if you have `dp` in the value for example:

**Is correct:**

`<dimen name="some_width">350dp</dimen>`

without `dp` is wrong:

`<dimen name="some_width">350</dimen>`

Answer (score 0):

```
<resources>  <dimen name="custom_marker_image">50dp</dimen>   <dimen name="custom_marker_padding">2dp</dimen>
<resources/>
```

So, go to `res > values > dimensions.xml` and right there include this code.