# Android custom view: How to update custom enum attribute via LiveData & data binding

Tags: android, kotlin, enums, android-databinding, android-livedata

I am building a custom view, which has a few custom attributes, two of which are enums. I am using databinding and MutableLiveData to update my views. This works without problems, but I am having trouble getting it to work with my enum. Can anyone help?

All code examples have been trimmed down to only show what's related to the problem. If something essential is missing, please point it out.
This is my layout:

```html
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        >

    <data>
        <variable
                name="viewModel"
                type="com.myapp.wifi.WifiItemViewModel"
                />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/margin_16"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/margin_16"
            >

        <components.wifi.WifiIconComponent
                android:id="@+id/img_wifi_icon"
                style="@style/WrapContent"
                android:layout_width="32dp"
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                app:wifiState="@{viewModel.wifiState}"
                app:termsAndConditionsAccepted="@{viewModel.termsAccepted}"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/guideline_start"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                />

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_wifi_name"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="@style/H5"
                android:text="@{viewModel.wifiName}"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/guideline_start"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/guideline_end"
                />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

My custom view is the `WifiIconComponent`. This is how I declare its custom attributes in `attrs.xml`:

```html
 <declare-styleable name="WifiIconComponent">
        <attr name="wifiState" format="enum">
            <enum name="NotAdded" value="0"/>
            <enum name="NotAvailable" value="1"/>
            <enum name="Available" value="2"/>
            <enum name="ConnectedWithoutInternet" value="3"/>
            <enum name="Connected" value="4"/>
        </attr>
        <attr name="termsAndConditionsAccepted" format="boolean"/>
        <attr name="iconSizing" format="enum">
            <enum name="small" value="0"/>
            <enum name="medium" value="1"/>
            <enum name="large" value="2"/>
        </attr>
    </declare-styleable>
```

And that is the view's class file:

```js
class WifiIconComponent @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : ImageView(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    private var wifiState = WifiState.NOT_ADDED
    private var termsAndConditionsAccepted = false
    private var iconSize = WifiIconSize.SMALL

    init {
        attrs?.let {
            val attributes = context.obtainStyledAttributes(it, R.styleable.WifiIconComponent)
            termsAndConditionsAccepted =
                attributes.getBoolean(R.styleable.WifiIconComponent_termsAndConditionsAccepted, false)
            iconSize = WifiIconSize.values()[attributes.getInt(R.styleable.WifiIconComponent_iconSizing, 0)]
            wifiState = WifiState.values()[attributes.getInt(R.styleable.WifiIconComponent_wifiState, 0)]
            attributes.recycle()
        }
        setImageDrawable(getStateIcon())
    }

    private fun getStateIcon(): Drawable? {
        val resource = when (iconSize) {
            WifiIconSize.SMALL -> getSmallIcon()
            WifiIconSize.MEDIUM -> getMediumIcon()
            WifiIconSize.LARGE -> getLargeIcon()
        }
        return context.getDrawable(resource)
    }

// rest of class

}
```

This is the viewModel referenced in the layout:

```js
class WifiItemViewModel(state: WifiConnectionState, val termsAccepted: Boolean) {

    val description = dummyArg.description
    var wifiState = MutableLiveData(state.wifiState)
    val wifiStateAsString = MutableLiveData(wifiState.value.toString())
    val wifiName = MutableLiveData(state.name)
    val switchVisibility = MutableLiveData(View.GONE)
    val activationState = MutableLiveData(state.isActivated)

    // the rest of the class is unrelated to the problem

}
```

Now if I just set whatever value I want in the layout, like `app:wifiState="Connected"`
, it all works fine. In the init block the set value gets properly translated into the right state of my enum I have in code:

```js
enum class WifiState {
    NOT_ADDED,
    NOT_AVAILABLE,
    AVAILABLE,
    CONNECTED_WITHOUT_INTERNET,
    CONNECTED_WITH_INTERNET
}
```

But if I bind it to a MutableLiveData in my viewModel (like I do in the above layout), I get this error:

```html
****/ data binding error ****msg:Cannot find the setter for attribute 'app:wifiState' with parameter type androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData<components.wifi.WifiState> on components.wifi.WifiIconComponent.
```

I assume this is related to having basically two different enums for the same values, one in code and one in xml. Is there a different way to do this? Or if my approach is fine, how do I get it to work?
Who can help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try adding a setter function to WifiIconComponent:

```
public fun setWifiState ( state : WifiState ) { wifeState = state }
```

which looks like a bit of a hack.

I had just the same problem, and finally solved it, I think, with a naming convention: the property in my custom view is called Mode, which has a custom setter:

```
class DisablableEditText

{
enum class EditMode { Disabled, Enabled }

var Mode = EditMode.Enabled
    set( value : EditMode )
    {
        when (value)
        {
            EditMode.Enabled -> _enableEdit()
            EditMode.Disabled -> _disableEdit()
        }
        field = value
    }
...
```

My attr.xml contains

```
<declare-styleable name="DisablableEditText">
    <attr name="Mode" format="enum" >
        <enum name="disabled" value="0"/>
        <enum name="enabled" value="1"/>
    </attr>
</declare-styleable>
```

The xml looks like this

```
  <ps.psandroid.views.DisablableEditText
   ...
        app:Mode="@{viewmodel.EditMode}" />
```

And viewmodel.EditMode like this

```
val EditMode : LiveData<DisablableEditText.EditMode> =
    Transformations.map( _mode ) { value ->
    when ( value )
    {
        Mode.VIEWING    -> DisablableEditText.EditMode.Disabled
        else            -> DisablableEditText.EditMode.Enabled
    }
}
```

So the attribute name is the same as my property. DataBinding looks for something like `setMode` with the right signature, and seems to pick up the custom setter.

Comment: This is years later, and i would never write my code like in this question anymore, but your way to approach that specific problem is clearly more helpful than my kinda hacky workaround. So I switched to this one as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be a real answer, but nevertheless it is how I solved my problem: I realized that I could just define custom integers in `res/values/integers.xml`, so I just got rid of my enums and switched to integers which can easily be accessed in both layout files and Java/Kotlin classes.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27782118/8746644) answer to another question sums up well how that works. Those integers then can easily be fed to the LiveData and update the view.